# The receipt is not balanced

Tags: quickbooks

I am trying to add a sales receipt to QuickBooks POS using the SDK. I receive this error:

The receipt is not balanced.

Here is my XML:

http://pastebin.com/MweDDRqU

My order total with tax is 21.25. Here are my items:

2 Shoes at $10 each

6.25% MA Sales Tax added to shoes only

Shipping worth $5

Discount worth $5

Total is $21.25.

I am unsure why the system says I am off $9.37. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where it's getting $9.37 from, but it's true that your receipt is NOT balanced.

The total amount is $21.25, but you indicated you only received $20.00 in payment.

```
<TenderCheckAdd>
    <CheckNumber>3</CheckNumber>
    <TenderAmount>20.0000000000</TenderAmount>
</TenderCheckAdd>
```

This is akin to the person at the cash register telling you your total is $21.25, and you handing them a $20 bill and walking out the door.

You still owe them $1.25.

Comment: Thanks. I added tax and I used the price field, instead of the extended price field.